# Let $W$ be the collection of all $2$ by $2$ symmetric matrices. Describe the orthogonal complement of $W$. (please)

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, vectors

A matrix is symmetric if $A^T=A$

And the standard basis for symmetric matrices is $\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ b & c\end{pmatrix}$ written as rows of a $2\times2$ matrix.

My question: How do i describe the orthogonal complement of $W$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A basis for the $2\times 2$ symmetric matrices is given by 
$$ \def\p#1#2#3#4{\begin{pmatrix} #1 & #2 \\ #3 & #4\end{pmatrix}}
  \p1000, \quad \p0001, \quad \p0110 $$
The inner product on ${\rm Mat}_2(\mathbf R)$ is given by $\def\<#1>{\left<#1\right>}\<A,B> := \def\tr{\mathrm{tr}}\tr(A^tB)$, now let $A = \p abcd$ be given, we have
\begin{align*}
  \<A, \p 1000> &= \tr\p a0b0\\
                &= a\\
  \<A, \p0001> &= \tr\p 0c0d\\
                &= d\\
  \<A, \p0110> &= \tr\p cadb\\
                &= b+c
\end{align*}
Hence $A$ is orthogonal to all symmetric matrices iff $a = d = b+c = 0$, so we have 
$$ {\rm Sym}_2(\mathbf R)^\bot = \left\{\p0a{-a}0\biggm| a \in \mathbf R\right\}, $$
the antisymmetric matrices.